FirstScript.java:3: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
Have all Selenium dependencies in same directory as FirstScript.java.
Why doesn't following work?


#!/bin/zsh
java -cp .\;`find . -name \*.jar | tr '\n' ';'` FirstScript.java



Thank you!

Oops should be colons instead of semicolons
java -cp .:find . -name \*.jar | tr '\n' ':' FirstScript.java
